# Android Tabbed Activity appear good on emulator bad on device

Tags: android, tabs, material-design

Using Android Studio created new project with Tabbed Activity.
When running it on android studio emulator it appear correct - the Tabs start from the left and end on the right.
But when running the app on my device I see the tabs start from the RIGHT and ends on the left side.
Also! its very strange cause when opened on the device I need to swipe right in order to continue to appearing left tabs.

please see attached photos to understand the problem:
[image: On emulator appear OKAY:]

[image: On device appear from the WRONG side:]

Comment: What device are you running it on?

Comment: samsung galaxy s6 edge

Comment: have a look at this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKhu4TQhIOg

Comment: I tried to change this setting in my Samsung galaxy s6 edge now, but made no change... still I see the tabs start from right to left instead of how it is show (good) on the emulator

Comment: try another phone will work fine , the problem not in your code , its on your phone setting I am sure as it works fine in emulator and if your try any other phone

Answer (score 0):

Second screen presents application running with RTL right-to-left layout. So somehow you must force showing RTL on your device or RTL is your default layout.

You could check your `Developer Options -> Force layout direction RTL` to be enabled

Comment: @YuvalLevy if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.